# Throwing card like animation in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

It's hard to explain but the animation i'm trying to achieve is...

I have a list of `div`'s and I want to animate them onto the screen. Like you're throwing them onto a table.

So my `html`:

```
  <ul class="content_anim_1__container_items">
    <li class="content_anim_1__image-item1"></li>
    <li class="content_anim_1__image-item2"></li>
    <li class="content_anim_1__image-item3"></li>
    <li class="content_anim_1__image-item4"></li>
    <li class="content_anim_1__image-item5"></li>
    <li class="content_anim_1__image-item6"></li>
    <li class="content_anim_1__image-item7"></li>
    <li class="content_anim_1__image-item8"></li>
    <li class="content_anim_1__image-item9"></li>
  </ul>
```

All the `li` tags are `position: absolute` and `right: -500px` then in my JS I do:

```
function activeAnim() {
  for(var x=0; x < $(".content_anim_1__container_items li").length; x++) {
    $(".content_anim_1__image-item1").addClass("activeAnim1");
    $(".content_anim_1__image-item2").addClass("activeAnim2");
    $(".content_anim_1__image-item3").addClass("activeAnim3");
    $(".content_anim_1__image-item4").addClass("activeAnim4");
    $(".content_anim_1__image-item5").addClass("activeAnim5");
    $(".content_anim_1__image-item6").addClass("activeAnim6");
    $(".content_anim_1__image-item7").addClass("activeAnim7");
    $(".content_anim_1__image-item8").addClass("activeAnim8");
    $(".content_anim_1__image-item9").addClass("activeAnim9");
  }
}


activeAnim();
```

To loop over my `divs` and append the class `activeAnim` which has something like `right: 40px; top: 20px;`

My issue is it just doesn't feel fluid enough.

I was reading up on animations and found an article basically explaining that I shouldn't animate using `left` and `right` but using `transform: translate3d()` link - https://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_movement_smoothly_using_css.htm

Is there any resources out there or tutorials to achieve what I'm looking for or close to it.

Comment: [This might help](https://tympanus.net/Development/Baraja/)

Comment: @BrettGregson oh man thanks dude! Yeah that's the similar animation i'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at:

- [Material design - Duration & easing](https://material.io/guidelines/motion/duration-easing.html#)
- [Material design - Movement](https://material.io/guidelines/motion/movement.html)

Use transform translate instead of top/left/right/bottom to improve performance. Play with the easing function. In those links you have some easing functions that you might find useful.